# If string contains an list item

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement

I'm looking for a way to check if an string contains anywhere in it, a list item

```
test = ['he', 'she', 'them']
string = 'hello'
if any(test in s for s in string):
    print 'yes'
```

I try this, and since 'he' is in 'hello' it should print yes, but i get

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

any help?

Comment: you're writing "if any <list> in <string>", and your error is telling you this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating a string object, iterate the list object `test`.

And check whether the test item is in `string`:

```
test = ['he', 'she', 'them']
string = 'hello'
if any(test_item  in string for test_item in test):
    print 'yes'
```